# swift create record and add record into relationship

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-data

I working with swift 4 for macOS.
I use core data with two entities:

- Person (in relationship with Book)
- Book (in relationship with Person)

**NSManagedObject Person**

```
import CoreData

@objc(Person)
public class Person: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var firstName: String!
    @NSManaged public var books: NSSet
}
```

**NSManagedObject Book**

```
import CoreData

@objc(Book)
public class Book: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged public var bookName: String!
    @NSManaged public var date: DateString!
    @NSManaged public var person: Person?
}
```

with this code i create a new person record:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Person", in: context)
let newPerson = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context) as! Person

newPerson.firstName = "Max"

do {
   try context.save()
} catch {print(error)}
```

now i would like to create directly a new record into Book if i create a new person record => bookName="Test" , date=Date()

is this possible with my used code `newPerson.books = ?`
or have i use the same code "new person record" (little bit modified) to create a book record?

Comment: You could also set the relationship from the book record `let book = ...`, `book.person = newPerson`

Comment: but i prefer the way to create a new book while i create a person. how can i create a book record with my existing code?

Comment: Same way as the person... `let bookEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Book", in: context); let newBook = NSManagedObject(entity: bookEntity!, insertInto: context) as! Book`

Comment: Now, if you mean that you want to create a default book and associate it with a person, just move the book creation logic to `Person`'s `awakeFromInsert`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make the new `Book` creation automatic. You need to have code that creates the instance. You have a couple of options:

1. Do it just like your code above. Any time you create a new `Person`, follow it with code that creates a `Book`.
2. Override `awakeFromInsert` on your `Person` class. In your override, add the code to create a new `Book`. Now you can create a new `Person` using your current code, and each new `Person` will create a new `Book` when you first create it.